# How to accept values to 2d List in dart

Tags: java, arrays, flutter, oop, dart

```
List list1  = [
 [1, 1, 1], 
 [1, 1, 1], 
 [1, 1, 1]
];

print(list1); 

}
```

Here, I've created a list with initialization, but I need to accept values from the console.

Comment: This is not a list but a two dimensional array. Hence you change values by assigning new value to arrays cell, like for example list1[0][0] = 100;

Comment: Also, what language are we talking about here? I am guessing Dart since `print` is a Dart method but your question is also tagged as Java?

Comment: Please clarify what you already *can* do, what you want to do next and where and why you struggle with that that. First step: *can* you read a value from the console?

Answer (score 1):

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  // Initialize an empty list to store user input
  List<List<int>> list1 = [];

  // Number of rows and columns
  int rows = 3;
  int columns = 3;

  // Loop through rows
  for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    // Initialize a temporary row list
    List<int> row = [];
    // Loop through columns
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
      // Take user input for each element
      stdout.write('Enter element at position (${i + 1}, ${j + 1}): ');
      int element = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!);
      // Append the element to the row list
      row.add(element);
    }
    // Append the row list to the main list1
    list1.add(row);
  }

  // Print the final list1
  print(list1);
}
```

To Accept Value from console you can use this approach.